# Strange garbage output from a simple printf()

Tags: c, gcc, printf, cygwin, character

This code leads to infinite garbage output on the console:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", L"Hello");
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("converted arg %d = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

If to keep just `wprintf` or just `printf` (in the `for`) - everything is OK. Also I tried `%S` instead of `%ls` in `wprintf`, but with the same result. It happens in MinGW as well.

This happens in the **last Cygwin (64), Windows 10**, gcc version is:

```
$ LANG= gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-9.3.0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-9.3.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-9.3.0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-9.3.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (GCC)
```

`$LANG` has correct value... I compile it with `gcc -o aaa.exe aaa.c`. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: What happens if you try just `%s` in the `wprintf` and `%hs` in the `printf`? (Assuming you are building with `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` defined.)

Comment: @AdrianMole tried - the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `wprintf()` in the loop too.

Once *orientation* is defined, stick to it.

---

> Each stream has an orientation. After a stream is associated with an external file, but before any
>   operations are performed on it, the stream is without orientation. Once a wide character input/output
>   function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a wide-oriented
>   stream. Similarly, once a byte input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation,
>   the stream becomes a byte-oriented stream.  ... C17dr § 7.21.2 4

Comment: hmm, I tried to printf() in the `for` before and then to `wprintf` and I get one 'H' only from the `wprintf`. Is the "orientation" the reason of it? So, I CANNOT to print wide-chars and usual chars on the same stream? Or there is some way to "reset" it? I never heard about such feature. Please, add the URL link to the answer. Thanks a lot, it seems that it's true..

Comment: @Paul-AG to reset: ".... Only a call to the `freopen` function or the `fwide`
function can otherwise alter the orientation of a stream. (A successful call to `freopen` removes any
orientation." is the rest of the citation

Comment: @Paul-AG *"Please, add the URL link to the answer."* - That is a quotation from the draft of the current C standard, § 7.21.2/4, not a quote from an answer anywhere on SO.